# teamcity build system or config variable name populated from dynamically generated reference

Tags: teamcity, buildconfiguration

All, any clues on how to do the following in the Build Parameter panel in teamcity 8.0.5?

property name : `system.project_fullName`
property value : `%dep.$mybuildID$.system.project_fullName%`

with `$mybuildID$` being a property defined in the same Panel

property name : `system.mybuildID`
property value : `BuildX`

The reason I need to do this is that I have a dependency to create between multiple projects for  two-step-style build projects.
I don't want to manually edit each property I am trying to import from my BuildX project - I only want to have one variable to edit in each build configuration. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in TeamCity to dynamically resolve parameter inside another parameter value. Won't it be an option to create a project with all needed dependencies configured and then copy this project. In this case build configurations and dependencies between them will be copied respectively and you do not have to configure anything manually.

Comment: No this is not helpfull as I have a bunch of configuration settings depending on the 1st build step - so each time I replicate the build to handle a new build I have so edit EACH property.
e.g. A1 dep of B1 - B1 need sot access multiple config props from A1, so I have to use for dep.mybuildIDA1.system.project_fullName to access project_fullName from A1. idem for example for system.project_shortName, I can access it using dep.mybuildIDA1.system.project_shortName.

Comment: Once I want to replicate this build for another component I have to edit each property e.g. dep.mybuildIDA1.system.project_shortName => dep.mybuildIDA2.system.project_shortName. idem for Fullname etc.